# issue in encoding data.frame strings

Tags: r, string, dataframe, extract

Some of the string in a data frame I have read from a csv file have an encoding issue.

This is how I read the data frame:

`data <- read.csv(file.choose(), colClasses = c(est_il_un_retweet="character", identifiant_du_tweet_genere_par_twitter="character", texte_du_tweet="character"))`

If I ask for the encoding of the problematic column I get this:

```
> Encoding(data$texte_du_tweet)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[7] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
...
```

And using enc2utf8() does not seem to work:

```
Encoding(enc2utf8(data$texte_du_tweet))
[1] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "UTF-8"   "unknown" "unknown"
[7] "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8" 
[13] "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"
```

Comment: Try using `charToRaw()`  to turn your strings into bytes and compare the bytes. It might be a difference in `Encoding()` between the two strings.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, how can I solve the issue? This is what I get: `> charToRaw(raw_stringDF1) == charToRaw(raw_stringDF2)
  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [12]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In charToRaw(raw_stringDF1) == charToRaw(raw_stringDF2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` (and a bunch of lines of FALSES)

Comment: I also get this: `> Encoding(raw_stringDF1)
[1] "UTF-8"
> Encoding(raw_stringDF2)
[1] "unknown"`

Comment: Just add the output of `charToRaw(raw_stringDF1)` and `charToRaw(raw_stringDF2)` to the question. Don't compare them right away (though the error message clearly indicates they have a different number of bytes so they are different)

Comment: I am trying to perform `enc2utf8()` on my data.frame columns...

Comment: I don't think the actual problem has been articulated. @DarioLacan what is your question exactly?

Comment: Hi Ista : I have an issue of encoding and even if I use enc2utf8() it does not manage to encode all my text. Please consider that the text is fully readable by human eye (no weird caracters).